# Smooth histogram in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I can plot a histogram (with absolute counts) of my data using `geom_histogram`, but this gives me bars, not a smooth line.

I can use `geom_density` to get a smooth line, but the axis is frequency, not counts.

Is it possible to get a smooth histogram with absolute counts on the y axis with `ggplot`?

Comment: I'm guessing you want a _scaled_ density plot, maybe? e.g. `geom_density(aes(y = ..count..))`?

Comment: @joran Yes, that's exactly what I want, thank you! By the way, what is the `..count..` syntax? What do the dots mean?

Comment: It's just a somewhat obtuse way to avoid name collisions. See `?stat_density`, including the Value section and the examples and you'll see it in use.